# System.in is not working with Scanner (NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, system.in

So I'm creating a simple programme that contains arrays and such, and my programme compiles perfectly. However, when I run it and input the name of my file (flight), my programme gives me the error `NoSuchElementException` I delved deeper by finding out whether System.in was available through the following code:

`System.out.println(System.in.available());`

This is the rest of my relevant code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FlightAirportController
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please name the Input File: ");
        System.out.println(System.in.available()); // checks if System.in is working: output is either 0 or 1.
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(input.next() + ".txt"));
        fileScanner.useDelimiter(", |\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: do you run your program from IntelliJ?

Comment: You are missing the file location

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(System.in.available());
```

This line always print zero, becose you can't write text so faster as needed.

1 will print in case you write text before this line work (very few milliseconds).

```
new File(input.next() + ".txt")
```

`Scanner.next()` return text until first space. If file name contains space you mast set delimeter with `Scanner.useDelimiter(pattern)`.

> Scanner.next throws NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are
>   available.

Solution:

use method `Scanner.hasNext()` - return true if inputStream contains character to read/ false - in otherwise.

If you need read Line, use `Scanner.hasNextLine()` and `Scanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the file location.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlightAirportController
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please name the Input File: ");
      System.out.println(System.in.available()); // checks if System.in is working: output is either 0 or 1.
      Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\..\\"+input.next() + ".txt"));
      fileScanner.useDelimiter(", |\n"); 
    }
}
```

`NoSuchElementException` Will come when you are calling `next` even if the `Scanner` has no next element to provide. Instead of `file.next()` use of `file.hasNext()` will be helpful.